# How to write EOF to STDIN popen in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, whiptail

I have the following command run through popen:

```
p = subprocess.popen(["/usr/bin/whiptail", "--title", "\"Progress\"", "--gauge", "\"\"", "6", "50", "0"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stding=subprocess.PIPE)
```

To stop the whiptail command from running I need to send EOF to stdin.

How do I send EOF to stdin in Python ?

or I just call p.terminate()

Comment: Tangentially, do you really want `Progress` in quotes -- as if it isn't really progress?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you need is to close the file used as standard input for your script.

So in your case it's `p.stdin.close()`.